# Nested while loop not working in Bash

Tags: bash

Beginner here so bear with me.  I am trying to compare homework submissions from a solution file and a student submission file.  The contents of each file have three problems, one per line:

```
problem 1 code
problem 2 code
problem 3 code
```

I want to compare each line in the solution with the corresponding line in the students submission.  I am using a for loop to run through each student file and a nested while loop to run through each line of the solution file and student file.  For some reason the script is completely ignoring the while loop.  I have put echoes between each line to see where the problem is(the echo $solution and echo $submission is just to check to see if the path is correct):

```
 for submission in /home/myfolder/submissions/*

    do
    echo 1
    solution=$(echo /home/myfolder/hwsolution/*)
    echo 2
    echo $solution
    echo $submission
            while read sans <&1 && read sol <&2
             do
    echo 3
             echo Student awnser is: $sans
             echo Solution is: $sol
    echo 4
            done 1<$(echo $submission) 2<$(echo $(echo $solution))
    echo 5
done
```

When I run it I get:

```
1
2
/home/myfolder/hwsolution/solution
/home/myfolder/submissions/student1
5
1
2
/home/myfolder/hwsolution/solution
/home/myfolder/submissions/student2
5
1
2
/home/myfolder/hwsolution/solution
/home/myfolder/submissions/student3
5
```

Comment: There's no nested while loop in your code, and it's not clear how the output you post relates to the output you *expect* or want.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what useful thing you expect `1<$(echo $submission)` or `2<$(echo $(echo $solution))` to accomplish. (Also, using file descriptor 1 or file descriptor 2 for input is a *really* bad idea, as those two are reserved for stdout and stderr, respectively).

Comment: ...do you maybe want to *read the contents of the files*? If so, then you want `<"$solution"`, with no `echo`.

Comment: I told you -- it's not ignoring them at all. It's trying to run the loop, but the `echo`s inside the loop don't work because you overrode stdout and stderr. (Also, it's not iterating over the lines in the file, but iterating over *the names of the files*, because of your unnecessary/inappropriate `echo`s in the process substitutions).

Comment: FD 0, FD 1 and FD 2 are reserved, so when you run `1<...` and `2<...`, you break any command or program inside the area subject to redirection that tries to log to stdout (FD 1) or stderr (FD 2). And because you broke the logging, you can't see any logs that tell you what you broke.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah I do!  when I do that it still ignores it.  Its as if there is no code written there.

Comment: "yeah I do" *what*? I don't know what you're telling me that you do. If you have code to show, [edit] it into the question.

Comment: If you're telling me "yeah I do" run `1<...` or `2<...`, well -- *obviously*; that's what's breaking your code, which I've tried to tell you several times now.

Comment: My bad I commented before your next comment came through on my end.  You are suggesting I change it to 1<"$submission" and 2<"$solution" correct.

Comment: No, I'm telling you to use `3<` and `4<`, not `1<` and `2<`, because `1` and `2` are reserved for output and errors.

Comment: When you overwrite FD 1, then you can no longer write output to the TTY, so `echo` no longer works, which is why you can't see any output from your `echo`s.

Comment: And when you overwrite FD 2 (stderr), then you also prevent `echo` from writing an error message describing that it couldn't write to FD 1, so even though the code in your loop runs, *you can't see its output at all*.

Comment: ...now, you'll *also* want to make it `3<"$submission"` and `4<"$solution"`, but that's almost a secondary concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ignoring the while loop -- **you're redirecting the file descriptors used for stdout and stderr**, so `echo` can't write to the console within it.

```
for submission in /home/myfolder/submissions/*; do
    solutions=( /home/myfolder/hwsolution/* )

    if (( ${#solutions[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -e ${solutions[0]} ]]; then
      solution=${solutions[0]}
    else
      echo "Multiple solution files found; don't know which to use" >&2
      printf ' - %q\n' "${solutions[@]}" >&2
      exit
    fi

    while read sans <&3 && read sol <&4; do
             echo "Student awnser is: $sans"
             echo "Solution is: $sol"
    done 3<"$submission" 4<"$solution"
done
```

The most immediate change is that we're redirecting **FD3 and FD4, not FD1 and FD2**.

Comment: I'm getting "multiple solution files found..." even though there is only one file in home/myfolder/hwsolution.  There will only ever be one file in there.

Comment: Added a `printf` to log the candidates, so you can see exactly what it thinks the list of files is, and thus figure out why/how you have something other than exactly one file.

Comment: I think it worked!  I forgot to delete the $ in solutions=( /home/myfolder/hwsolution/* ).  You're a life saver man.  So what is this code actually doing?  I don't quite understand the &3 and &4.  I got that suggestion from another post but we have not learned about that in my class.

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial is a good place to start.

Comment: ...btw, [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is a good related resource, covering `read` in detail.